# Rails redirect_to with :anchor fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, redirect, anchor

I have this code in my controller:

```
redirect_to projects_path(:anchor => 'p5')
```

It works fine in Chrome, FF, and Safari, and the browser url shows:

```
/projects#p5
```

However, IE ignores the anchor altogether, and uses the url without it:

```
/projects
```

Is there a workaround to this? When will IE cease to exist?

Edit:

The issue is with IE7.

Per a comment below, outputting `<%= (debug projects_path(:anchor => 'p5')).html_safe %>` gives:

```
--- /projects#p5
...
```

Comment: does the anchor show when you hover over the link?

Comment: what's the output for different browsers of **<%= (debug projects_path(:anchor => 'p5')).html_safe %>**? do you have *resources :projects* route?

Comment: This is *not* a Ruby on Rails problem.  It is specific to Internet Explorer.  Sorry, I don't have a work-around for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 and below don't retain anchors/fragments on redirects.  I think you need to find another way of accomplishing what you want with the redirect.